# Logstash: 1 input & multiple output files

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

We have a running software which publishes information through Apache Kafka. Due to customer requirements all the information is collected and written to txt and csv files. The customer so far had only 1 project but they want to now add a second project and would  like to filter out the information into 2 separate files. In fact they would like 1 project to continue to be pushed into a txt file as it happens now, but the information for the second project to be pushed directly to a database. Is this possible? Can anyone point me on where to find more information?

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => ["10.1.83.132:9192"]
    group_id => ["my_plugin_id"]
    topics => "survey-result"
    codec => json
    security_protocol => ["SSL"]
    ssl_truststore_location => ["/home/bitnami/kafka.client.truststore.jks"]
    ssl_truststore_password => ["changeit"]
    ssl_endpoint_identification_algorithm => [""]
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
    }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
      index => "survey-result"
      workers => 1
      codec => json
    }
   file {
        path => "/sadata/saexport-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.txt"
        # codec => line { format => "custom format: %{message}"}
 }

   csv {
        # elastic field name
        fields => ["data.integrationName", "data.contextData.UCID", "data.contextData.ANI", "data.reason.reason", "data.status"]
        # separator => ","
        # This is path where we store output.   
        path => "/sadata/saexport.%{+YYYY-MM-dd-hh}.csv"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, you need to use conditionals in your output to direct the messages to the correct destination based on one or more fields.

for example:

```
output {
    if [fieldName] == "stringA" {
        output for this type of message
    }
    if [fieldName] == "stringB" {
        output for this type of message
    }
    if [fieldName] == "stringN" {
        output for this type of message
    }
}
```

You will need a field to filter on, this field can be present on the document or you can add it if you are going to use multiple inputs using the `tags` or `type` options from the [common options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-common-options) available in all inputs.

This [part of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) has some example about using conditionals.